How to switch between textures for different objects?
I have two objects with the same material.
Can I change the texture of just one of them without creating a new material each time?
How can I drive the Offset value of the Image sequence texture node from whithin a single material node tree.


I like what you tried to do with the object data property, but there’s no way to use a different object data property with each object for the same material, unless you did some stuff with attribute storing in geometry nodes, perhaps.

I don’t think there’s any way around having some kind of duplication, either different materials or different mesh data blocks with different UV maps.

instead of a driver use an Attribute node set to object, and plug the output of the attribute into the mix factor of a Mix RGB node. Use 2 different image texture nodes

Does this answer your question? Using independently two values of two object that share the same material. This is a very similar subject and there are different methods in the answers. One of them might be applicable for your problem. @TheLabCat Why is there no way? There are different ways.

@GordonBrinkmann This can be a solution only if there are 2 textures, maximum 4. But what to do if there are a lot of textures and it is unknown how many there are? It will be very inconvenient and very expensive

You can use Pass Index to drive some values of material nodes (in my simple example first Suzanne has index 0, while second has index 1, but you can build some more complicated trees).

A (known) multiple images version:

For unknown number of textures (like an image sequence) you should ask a specific question about how to "read" (and maybe use as new driver) the Object Info value inside the material node tree and/or how to manipulate the offset of the Image sequence texture node from inside the material node tree: I didn't find a way yet.

You could have taken the image from Robin's answer to the duplicate question from two days ago, would have saved you some effort

OK. What to do if there are more than 2 textures?
For example 10. or unknown quantity
